# Why does the surjectivity of the canonical projection $\pi:G\to G/N$ imply uniqueness of $\tilde \varphi: G/N \to H$

Tags: group-theory, functions, group-homomorphism, universal-property

Let's look at the universal property of quotient groups:

> Let $\varphi:G \to H$ be a homomorphism, $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$
>    and $\pi:G \to G/N$ the canonical projection. If $N \le \ker \varphi$,
>    there is a homomorphism $\tilde \varphi: G/N \to H$ such that $$\tilde
>  \varphi \circ \pi = \varphi.$$

The proof in my book for this universal property states that the uniqueness of $\tilde \varphi$ follows directly from the surjectivity of the canonical projection $\pi$.

However, i don't understand, how and why.

How would a comprehensive proof of the uniqueness of $\tilde \varphi$ look like, rather than stating "follows from surjectivity"? In other words:

Why would $\tilde \varphi$ *not* be unique if $\pi$ wasn't surjective?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Jantzen - Algebra p.21

Comment: If $\pi$ were not surjective it is possible that one could define a homomorphism which has all the same values on the image of $\pi$ but is not the same on the rest of $G$

Comment: I dont understand, $\operatorname{Im} \pi \not\subset G$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surjective functions can be cancelled on the right:

If $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective, and $g,h\colon B\to C$ are functions such that $g\circ f = h\circ f$, then $g=h$. For, given $b\in B$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Therefore,
$$g(b) = g(f(a)) = h(f(a)) = h(b),$$
so $g(b)=h(b)$ for all $b\in B$, hence $g=h$.

(In fact, this property *characterizes* surjective functions in set theory).

So suppose that you have two functions, $\overline{\varphi},\overline{\phi}\colon G/N\to H$ such that $\overline{\varphi}\circ \pi = \overline{\phi}\circ \pi$. Since $\pi$ is surjective, this immediately implies that $\overline{\varphi}=\overline{\phi}$.

---

“How would $\overline{\phi}$ not be unique if $\pi$ wasn’t surjective?” is a counterfactual question.

But...

In general, if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then there always exists a group $K$ and group homomorphisms $f,g\colon G\to K$ such that $f(h)=g(h)$ for every $h\in H$, but $f\neq g$. A construction is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443049/show-that-f-is-an-epimorphism-of-groups-if-and-only-if-f-is-surjective-as-a).

So *if*, **somehow** (complete counterfactual, but whatever), $\pi \colon G\to G/N$ were not surjective, then you would be able to construct a group $H$ and homomorphism $f,g\colon G/N \to H$ such that $f\circ\pi = g\circ\pi$, but $f\neq g$. Letting $\varphi=f\circ \pi$ would give you a map with $N\subseteq \mathrm{ker}(\varphi)$, but with both $f,g\colon G/N\to K$ satisfying the conclusion.

Comment: beautiful, thank you Arturo.

Comment: do you happen to know an example for a function $f:A \to B$ that is not surjective with two functions $g,h: B\to C$ such that $f\circ g = f \circ h$ but due to $f$ not being surjective $g \not=h$?

Comment: @Zest: As I said, that property **characterizes** surjective functions. If $f\colon A\to B$ is not surjective, let $C=\{0,1\}$. Define $g\colon B\to C$ by $g(b)=0$ for all $b$; define $h\colon B\to C$ by $g(b)=0$ if $b\in f(A)$, and $g(b)=1$ otherwise.

Comment: @Zest: For groups it’s more complicated (because the functions have to be morphisms), but I *linked* to a construction. You can find it there.

Comment: @Zest: And you have the composition going the wrong way. It’s $g\circ f = h\circ f$. Given your definitions, $f\circ g$ is nonsense: the range of $g$ is $C$, but the domain of $f$ is $A$.

Comment: @Zest: For set theoretic functions, look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63347/proof-that-a-bijection-has-unique-two-sided-inverse) and maybe try to prove the results yourself? At least the ones that don’t invoke proving an equivalence with the Axiom of Choice? They are both rather basic *and* extremely important.

Comment: Thanks for your help Arturo, sorry that was a typo regarding the composition.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a commutative diagram.  There's only one way that works, letting $\tilde\phi(gN)=\phi(π^{-1}(gN)$.  $π$ surjective means $π^{-1}(gN)\ne\emptyset$.  And $N\le\operatorname{ker}\phi$ ensures it is well defined.

Comment: Thanks @ArturoMagidin.  I spelled it wrong.