# Does a map being bijective have the same meaning as having an inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is probably a pretty general question and might require a little more information, but suppose that a function with a defined Domain and Co-Domain has an inverse function whose Domain is the Co-Domain of the original function and whose Co-Domain is the Domain of the original function.

Is this the same thing as the function being bijective?  The reason I ask is that I've noticed a lot of the proofs in my Algebra class that involve showing a function is a bijection consist of only defining an inverse function and nothing more.

Comment: A function from $X$ to $Y$ is one-to-one if and only if it has a left inverse; it is surjective if and only if it has a right inverse; and it is bijective if and only if it has a (two-sided) inverse. This is a theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by left and right inverses?

Comment: If $f\colon X\to Y$, then a function $g\colon Y\to X$ is (i) a left inverse of $f$ if and only if $g\circ f = \mathrm{id}_X$; (ii) a right inverse of $f$ if and only if $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_Y$; and (iii) a (two-sided) inverse of $f$ if and only if $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_Y$ *and* $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_X$, if and only if it is both a left and a right inverse of $f$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63347/proof-that-a-bijection-has-unique-two-sided-inverse),